# Could I give higher priority to transactions to mined right away?

Tags: private-blockchain, contract-deployment, block-interval, miner

For example on Linux we can give higher priority to processes for Linux Kernel to schedule. I am the owner of my Private Ethereum Network. As an owner, could I give higher priority to deploy or mine my contract's selected methods, like on Linux? or is it against to Ethereum.

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All smart contract functions calls as well as smart contract deployments are inherently transactions. Each transaction gets incorporated into a block whenever a miner chooses to do so. Currently in the public Ethereum main chain, most transactions get incorporated into the next block right away (in contrast to the Bitcoin blockchain). However, if things do get crowded and miners do not include your transaction right away you can increase the gas price. This is analogous to a "higher priority" in other systems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802037/in-ethereum-what-is-gas-how-is-it-used-and-what-is-the-difference-between-st.

In case of your private network you might be waiting simply for the next block (in average 14s). If this is too slow for you and you anyway want to work in a private network consider using e.g. Eris:db by Monax for your setting instead of Ethereum.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to send my transaction with highest gasPrice value (for example: `myContract.hello(var, {from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gasPrice: 50000000000 }); )`, since as I understand unused gas will be automatically and immediately refunded?

Comment: You confuse `startgas` and `gasprice`. Check the link that I added to my comment. If you set a crazy high price then these ether are gone. Important for high priority is the price, not the `startgas` amount.

Comment: Sorry they both kind of mixed up. I gave the example from the link you shared. I set a very large number to `gasprice` to give high priority as you suggested. isn't it the right way to do it?

Comment: You said: "Important for high priority is the price" (`price`==`gasprice`)? @Sebastian.

Comment: Correct, I meant `gasprice`.