# For higher priority would it be a good idea to send a transaction with highest gasPrice?

Tags: gas, gas-limit

I am little bit lost related to gas refund issue. On the following answer: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/11017/4575
it has been mentioned that:

> However, if things do get crowded and miners do not include your
> transaction right away you can increase the gas price. This is
> analogous to a "higher priority" in other systems:
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802037/in-ethereum-what-is-gas-how-is-it-used-and-what-is-the-difference-between-st.

Therefore to get a higher priority for a transaction to be mined, would it be a good idea to send a transaction with highest gasPrice (for example: `myContract.hello(var, {from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 99570000 , gasPrice: 50000000000 });` ), since as I understand unused gas will be automatically and immediately refunded. if the `gasUsed` for the `hello()` function is 1000000, will I get refund for 50000000000 - 1000000 ? or all the gas I send via transaction will be spent?

Please note that I updated my question based on @Badr Bellaj's guidance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't confuse `gas` value with `gasprice`.

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({/* ... */,gas: 99570000 , gasPrice: 12345});
```

Miners will Prioritize the transactions with a higher gas price not a gas value (how much gas are you providing to be used to execute your transaction). the miners set a gasprice(the gas price you are willing to pay in ether for each unit of gas) whiting the network if you send a transaction with a price below your transaction will not be proceeded otherwise more you raise your gas price more you Prioritize your transaction.
your transaction `fee = consumed_gas * gas_price.`
your function consumes n gas you get refunded `gas_value-n`;

Comment: Thank you for your answer. ex: `web3.eth.sendTransaction({/* ... */, gas: 99570000 , gasPrice: 50000000000});` in either cases when I give a very high value for a transaction that is using a low gas (for example: 1000000), will there be any refund? I am going to call the same transaction inside a infinite loop, so I was not sure that using a large gasPrice may lead me to have insufficient gas much quickly or not.

Comment: your transaction execution consumes gas and you pay using gasprice. the billing will be consumed_gas*gas_price. so every time the calculation reduces the gas value. e.g you send a transaction with 1234 gas and the function consumes 4 gas you get refunded 1230 gas (unite). Think of a gas like a vocher in a casino, you play with but the casino who sets its value so you play with units=vocher not money.

Comment: "Infinite Loop"? The EVM is designed with the goal of making sure an infinite loop isn't possible.

Comment: Ups sorry for the confusion, I implemented a infinite loop on my bash script so every 20 seconds it will call the same transaction. @RobHitchens

Comment: It is much clear now, thanks mate. `(consumed_gas == n)` ? and for the refund amount calculation, should we also multiply with `gasprice` =>  `(gas_value-n) * gas_price` ? @BadrBellaj.

Comment: No. The remaining gas units are refunded